# Using jquery-cookie plugin to count number of time user visits site

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to count the number of times a user visits my site, using the [JQuery Cookie plugin.](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) Setting a reading the cookie is super simple and no problem, but I can't quite figure out how to increment the value of the cookie each time the user returns.

Comment: Read the cookie, add 1 to it, save the cookie.

Comment: Your question is not very clear about what the problem is.

Comment: I can set a cookie using `$.cookie("visits",1)`, however I am unable to find a way to increment the value of the cookie based on the number of subsequent visits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function update_visit_count() {
    // Get the old visit count, or 0 if this is his first time
    var visits = $.cookie("visits") || 0;
    // Add 1 to it
    visits++;
    // Save the updated cookie
    $.cookie("visits", visits);
}
```